# Disambiguating or burninating the [movies] tag

Tags: support, retag-request

*Another update* – went through the tag three times now. We're down to 50 questions left. If you still see anything that'd be left tagged poorly, please don't hesitate to fix it.

---

*Update after 4/0 on JourneymanGeek's answer:* I went through the tagged questions and fixed missing tags / retagged. If the tag should be nuked, go for it.

---

[movies](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/movies) (x95) seems very ambiguous. I guess we can split them up into more precise tags like:

- [video-encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-encoding)
- [video-conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-conversion)
- [video-playback](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-playback)
- …

What do you think – should we just nuke this tag and let the questions stay as they are, or should we go through them and re-tag appropriately?

**Please post your idea below, we can then agree on a procedure to re-tag appropriately.**

Comment: I particularly like the bolded part of this post.

Comment: I'm for nuking the tag

Comment: Tags are auto-deleted when unused after a while.

Comment: @DanielBeck I didn't remove the tag from all 95 questions manually – who would do that *cough cough*! I just fixed the ones that would have bad tags after a possible burnination.

Comment: There seem to be questions that would be rather poorly tagged if [movies] was erased.  Down to about 50 questions, perhaps someone could take a look?

Comment: @Rebecca Can you give me an example of what question would be poorly tagged *without* `[movies]`? I went through them three times now.

Answer (score 5):

I personally would advocate nukeing the tag till it glows, and burninating it in the dark. Where the only tag is movies or the current tag is unclear, retagging would be necessary.

I think the questions below would be a example of what would need retagging.

[How to watch .MOV files without QuickTime?](https://superuser.com/questions/4118/how-to-listen-mov-file-without-quicktime) (quicktime)

[How to create subtitle files and add them to a video?](https://superuser.com/questions/48668/add-subtitle-to-a-movie) (subtitle)

https://superuser.com/questions/16045/is-there-a-way-to-import-blockbuster-com-queue-into-netflix (does this one even belong on SU?)

[Is it technically possible to make a self-destructing movie clip?](https://superuser.com/questions/382779/is-it-technically-possible-to-make-a-movie-clip-that-autodustructs-when-it-finis) (i have no clue about this one)

[Can I watch 3D movies on my computer just using 3D glasses and my normal monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/382421/can-i-watch-3d-movies-on-my-computer-just-using-3d-glasses-and-my-normal-monitor)

Comment: Went through them. The tag can be nuked now, I guess.